# Fuel UX - Hook onto change event of wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, fuelux

According to the [documentation](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/#wizard), I should be able to hook onto the change event of the Fuel UX wizard component. But for the life of me I cant figure out how. I'm still new-ish to jquery and javascript.

**Javascript** I've tried the following

```
var wizard = $('#MyWizard');

wizard.on('change', '.wizard', function () {
    alert('OH SNAP!');
});

wizard.wizard().on('change', function () {
    alert('OH SNAP!');
});
```

... and a few other variations to no success.

I think I'm messing up the basics somewhere. How would i go about adding  a custom event to the on change event.
(as id like to only have one content area, but on the change event id like to have the server provide me with the required content to fill each wizard step)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was painfully close to what I needed to do.

```
 var wizard = $('#MyWizard');

 wizard.on('change', function (e, data) {
      console.log('change');      
 });

 wizard.on('changed', function (e, data) {
      console.log('changed');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

First there is no myWizard just a MyWizard element. Second DIV elements have no change event. You just can add an click event to your buttons like:

```
<button class="btn btn-mini btn-prev" disabled="disabled" id="prev"><div class="icon-arrow-left"></div>Prev</button>
```

and then:

```
$('#prev').click(function () { alert('OH SNAP!'); });
```